# RichFaces: Work with two modalPanel

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces, modal-dialog

I've got a problem with the `rich:modalPanel`.
I have a`modalPanel` shown by a `rich:menuItem`.

```
<rich:menuItem value="#{lang.msg_edit}" submitMode="none" id="editLink">
<rich:componentControl for="modalEditPanelId"
    attachTo="editLink" operation="show" event="onclick" />
</rich:menuItem>
```

In this `modalPanel` there is a `rich:fileUpload` and during the execution of the `fileUploadListener` method, I want to hide thr current `modalPanel` and show a different panel asking about the confirmation of an operation to the user.

Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 0):

In RichFaces 4.0.0 you must be able to use this kind of code :

```
<h:form>
    <a4j:commandButton value="Upload" oncomplete="#{rich:component('panelFileUpload')}.show(); return false;" />

    <rich:modalPanel id="panelFileUpload">
        <rich:fileUpload>
            <a4j:ajax event="uploadcomplete" execute="@none" oncomplete="#{rich:component('panelFileUpload')}.hide(); #{rich:component('panelConfirmation')}.show();" />
        </rich:fileUpload>
    </rich:modalPanel>

    <rich:modalPanel id="panelConfirmation">
        <h:outputText value="Your file was uploaded." />
    </rich:modalPanel>
</h:form>
```

In RichFaces 3.X.X you must use `Richfaces.showModalPanel()` and `Richfaces.hideModalPanel()` instead.

Hope it helps!